# XML Validation error. I dont follow what the error means

Tags: xml

Error

```
File C:\Users\Randy\Documents\XML\case1\jw.xml is not valid.
Value '0:45:44.0Z' is not allowed for attribute 'length'.
    Hint: A valid value would be '14:20:00.0Z'.
    Error location: inventory / album / tracks / @length
    Details
        cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: For type definition 'xs:time' the   string '0:45:44.0Z' does not match a literal in the lexical space of built-in type definition 'xs:time'.
        cvc-simple-type.1: For type definition 'xs:time' the string '0:45:44.0Z' is not valid.
        cvc-attribute.3: Value '0:45:44.0Z' of attribute 'length' does not match simple type definition 'xs:time'.
        cvc-complex-type.3.1: The attribute 'length' of complex type '{anonymous}' is not valid.
        cvc-elt.5.2.1: The element <tracks> is not valid with respect to the actual type definition '{anonymous}'.
```

Code

```
  <inventory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="music.xsd">
  <album category="Modern" albumID="JW001305">
  <title>Kind of Blue</title>
  <artist>Miles Davis</artist>
  <artist>John Coltrane</artist>
  <tracks length="0:45:44.0Z">
     <track length="0:9:22">So What</track>
     <track length="0:9:46">Freddie Freeloader</track>
     <track length="0:5:37">Blue in Green</track>
     <track length="0:11:33">All Blues</track>
     <track length="0:9:26">Flamenco Sketches</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Bebop" albumID="JW001312">
  <title>Cookin'</title>
  <artist>Miles Davis</artist>
  <tracks length="0:35:13">
     <track length="0:5:57">My Funny Valentine</track>
     <track length="0:9:53">Blues by Five</track>
     <track length="0:4:22">Airegin</track>
     <track length="0:13:03">Tune-Up</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Modern" albumID="JW015011">
  <title>Blue Train</title>
  <artist>John Coltrane</artist>
  <tracks length="0:41:54">
     <track length="0:10:39">Blue Train</track>
     <track length="0:9:06">Moment's Notice</track>
     <track length="0:7:11">Locomotion</track>
     <track length="0:7:55">I'm Old Fashioned</track>
     <track length="0:7:03">Lazy Bird</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Modern" albumID="JW002210">
  <title>Sarah Vaughan</title>
  <artist>Sarah Vaughan</artist>
  <artist>Clifford Brown</artist>
  <tracks length="0:45:30">
     <track length="0:3:58">Lullaby of Birdland</track>
     <track length="0:6:18">April in Paris</track>
     <track length="0:4:10">He's My Guy</track>
     <track length="0:5:49">Jim</track>
     <track length="0:4:41">You're not the Kind</track>
     <track length="0:4:48">Embraceable You</track>
     <track length="0:5:08">I'm Glad there is You</track>
     <track length="0:5:43">September Song</track>
     <track length="0:4:55">It's Crazy</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Swing" albumID="JW014501">
  <title>Ellington at Newport</title>
  <artist>Duke Ellington</artist>
  <tracks length="1:25:50">
     <track length="0:1:10">The Star Spangled Banner</track>
     <track length="0:3:36">Introduction</track>
     <track length="0:6:21">Black and Tan Fantasy</track>
     <track length="0:3:34">Tea for Two</track>
     <track length="0:4:27">Take the A Train</track>
     <track length="0:8:10">Festival Junction</track>
     <track length="0:7:09">Blues to be There</track>
     <track length="0:5:33">Newport Up</track>
     <track length="0:3:52">Sophisticated Lady</track>
     <track length="0:3:50">Day In, Day Out</track>
     <track length="0:14:20">Dimuendo in Blue/Crescendo in Blue</track>
     <track length="0:0:44">Annoucements, Pandemonium</track>
     <track length="0:3:38">I Got it Bad (and That Ain't Good)</track>
     <track length="0:4:46">Jeep's Blues</track>
     <track length="0:2:49">Tulip or Turnip</track>
     <track length="0:1:08">Riot Prevention</track>
     <track length="0:9:13">Skin Deep</track>
     <track length="0:1:30">Mood Indigo</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Modern" albumID="JW024181">
  <title>Saxophone Colossus</title>
  <artist>Sonny Rollins</artist>
  <tracks length="0:39:51">
     <track length="0:6:46">St. Thomas</track>
     <track length="0:6:28">You Don't Know What Love Is</track>
     <track length="0:5:13">Strode Rode</track>
     <track length="0:10:06">Moritat</track>
     <track length="0:11:18">Blue 7</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  <album category="Bebop" albumID="JW031031">
  <title>The Cole Porter Songbook</title>
  <artist>Charlie Parker</artist>
  <artist>Cole Porter</artist>      
  <tracks length="0:38:56">
     <track length="0:3:24">Easy to Love</track>
     <track length="0:3:10">Begin the Beguine</track>
     <track length="0:2:45">Night and Day</track>
     <track length="0:2:38">What is This Thing Called Love</track>
     <track length="0:3:18">In the Still of the Night</track>
     <track length="0:3:31">I Get a Kick Out of You</track>
     <track length="0:2:39">Just One of Those Things</track>
     <track length="0:3:17">My Heart Belongs to Daddy</track>
     <track length="0:3:31">I've Got You Under My Skin</track>
     <track length="0:5:33">Love for Sale</track>
     <track length="0:5:10">I Love Paris</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>   
  <album category="Modern" albumID="JW061051">
  <title>The Sound of Jazz</title>
  <artist>Billie Holiday</artist>
  <artist>Count Basie</artist>
  <artist>Red Allen</artist>
  <artist>Lester Young</artist>
  <artist>Coleman Hawkins</artist>  
  <tracks length="0:41:41">
     <track length="0:4:46">Wild Man Blues</track>
     <track length="0:4:57">Rosetta</track>
     <track length="0:6:19">Fine and Mellow</track>
     <track length="0:6:53">Blues</track>
     <track length="0:4:27">I Left my Baby</track>
     <track length="0:4:43">The Train and the River</track>
     <track length="0:3:43">Nervous</track>
     <track length="0:5:53">Dickie's Dream</track>
  </tracks>
  </album>
  </inventory>
```

I missed the xsd file

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:simpleType name="albumIDType">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:ID">
    <xsd:pattern value="JW\d{6}" />
 </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="jazzType">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="New Orleans" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="Swing" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="Bebop" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="Modern" />
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>

 <xsd:element name="inventory">
 <xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="album" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="artist" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="unbounded" />
          <xsd:element name="tracks">
             <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element name="track" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                         <xsd:simpleContent>
                            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                               <xsd:attribute name="length" type="xsd:time"  use="optional" />
                            </xsd:extension>
                         </xsd:simpleContent>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                   </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="length" type="xsd:time" use="optional" />
             </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="category" type="jazzType" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="albumID" type="albumIDType" use="required" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    </xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this definition of `xs:time`:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="time">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:time">
    <xsd:pattern value="(([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9]){2}(\.[0-9]+)?" /> 
    <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:minInclusive value="00:00:00" /> 
    </xsd:annotation>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Form the `pattern` element, is appears that the hours, minutes, and seconds portions must have each have two digits. That is, your `length` values must each have the format

```
hh:mm:ss
```

followed by an optional time zone

Comment: In the provided code, some of the values only have one digit. For example, the very first `length` value is "0:45:44.0Z", where it should actually be "00:45:44.0Z" (note, there are two zeros in the hour place)

Comment: Yes thank you for your help is there a way to require one digit instead of two.

Comment: The only way I can think of is for you to make your own schema (not sure if your situation requires the use of w3c's schema or not). In the custom schema, you could make your own `simpleType` that looks almost the same as `xs:time`. The `pattern` element should instead have a `value` of something like `(([0]?[0-9])|([1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:([0]?[0-9])|([1-5][0-9])){2}(\.[0-9]+)?`. (You might be able to turn `[0]` and `[1]` into `0` and `1` respectively. I'm not sure, so maybe play around with it, see what happens).